# Include Foundation Variables in Multiple SCSS Files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use Foundation 5 in a Rails 4 app. The problem I am having is I would like to have some custom CSS in addition to Foundation. In my CSS I would like to use some of the variables from Foundation. To use them I did added the following to the top of my scss file

```
$include-html-classes: false;
@import "foundation/components/global";
```

This works great except there is some junk still included on each page. According to https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1629 this shouldn't happen.

If you look at the source here https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss then you can see that the meta stuff starting at line 284 will be included.

This is a problem since it will be included on every page that I want to use the variables/mixins on. Rails 4 combines all the css files into one which will have this same code over and over again...

Is there any way to include this file without it including any text?

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered that using

```
@import "foundation/functions";
@include exports("global") {}
@import "foundation/components/global";
```

will include all the variables and mixins but won't add anything to your scss file!

I believe this is because the exports function is there to prevent css from being duplicated every time the global file is included. By having the fake exports function call it thinks it's already added the css.